# iOS device debug console length

Tags: iphone, ios, debugging, console

Greetings all.

Is there a way to increase the size of an iOS device's debug console?  There are times that my app crashes during testing while not connected to my Mac, but by the time I retrieve the console it appears to have rolled over.

Thanks for the help.

--John

Answer (score 1):

I would also be very interested in knowing how to accomplish this.  We are developing an app that works with MFi and can run for hours on end.  It is crashing after seven to eight hours.  I can catch it within and hour but the console has rolled over.  The crash logs are turning up nothing.